# How to get filter value from URL only if it exists

Tags: javascript, search

**Context:**
I have a script for a search page that retrieves the value for the selected filter from the URL and appends the text " *in 'filter'.*" to the h1 heading on the search results page.

For example, if you search for ‘sql’ and apply the ‘Installation guide’ filter, the URL will show `.../Search.htm?q=sql&f=Installation%20Guide` and the search results page will say:
*Your search for "sql" returned 9 results in Installation Guide.*

However, if no filter is selected, there is no '`f=`' and a blank is appended. In that case, the search results page will say:
*Your search for "sql" returned 9 results in .*

Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var filter=(window.location.search.split('&').splice(1)) //Creates a "filter" variable whose value is the filter text.
filter = decodeURI(filter) //Removes the codes used for spaces.

filter = filter.substring(2) //Removes "f=" at the beginning.

var $span = $( document.createElement('span') ); //Creates a span element to contain the new text.

$span.addClass('filter'); //Adds the class filter to the span in case you would need to edit the styling.
$span.text(" in  "+'' + filter +'' + ".")  //Inserts text and the value from the URL.
$("h1").append($span) //Appends the new span to the existing string.

});
```

**Question:**
How can I modify the script to only report the filter if it's selected (if 'f=' exists)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see: [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API to parse url instead of writing a custom logic for it. `URL.searchParams` will parse all the query filters in the url and provide a proper api to get them. See the code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var filter = url.searchParams.get("f");

    if (filter) {
        var $span = $(document.createElement('span')); //Creates a span element to contain the new text.

        $span.addClass('filter'); //Adds the class filter to the span in case you would need to edit the styling.
        $span.text(" in  " + '' + filter + '' + ".") //Inserts text and the value from the URL.
        $("h1").append($span) //Appends the new span to the existing string.
    }
});
```